# Technical term for an outrageous exaggeration

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I have a mind blank for a term in English.

I wanted to describe a sentence I made. It's a technical term for when making an outrageous claim, not based in fact, but used for the purpose of impressing.

For example "The best show in the universe!"

Jeremy Clarkson often makes this kind of statement.

Comment: And here I was, thinking we Americans had cornered the market on hyperbole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're likely thinking of the word [hyperbole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hyperbole):

> hyperbole (countable and uncountable, plural hyperboles)
>
> (uncountable, rhetoric, literature)
>    Deliberate or unintentional overstatement, particularly extreme overstatement.
>
> (countable) 
>  An instance or example of such overstatement.

Answer (score 1):

***puffery***

> Advertising or sales presentation relying on exaggerations, opinions,
>   and superlatives, with little or no credible evidence to support its
>   vague claims. Puffery may be tolerated to an extent so long as it does
>   not amount to misrepresentation (false claim of possessing certain
>   positive attributes or of not possessing certain negative attributes).
>   [Business Dictionary](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/puffery.html)
>
> In everyday language, **puffery** refers to exaggerated or false
>   praise. In law, puffery is a promotional statement or claim that
>   expresses subjective rather than objective views, which no "reasonable
>   person" would take literally. Puffery serves to "puff up" an
>   exaggerated image of what is being described and is especially
>   featured in testimonials.
>   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffery)

Answer (score 0):

an **overstatement**  [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/overstatement)

> making to seem more important than it really is
>
> Synonyms:
>       exaggeration, magnification
>
> Type of:
>       deceit, deception, misrepresentation
>
> ```
> a misleading falsehood
> ```

As in:

> I think it’s an overstatement to say we’re at the brink of war,” says
>   Rep. @JAHimes ... 
>       Washington Times 2018